# How does system clock increase its tick counter

Tags: linux-kernel

From what I currently understand, that system clock increase its tick counter separately from RTC (hardware clock) when linux is up. I think it is maintained internally by kernel by reading timer interrupt.

So how exactly the mechanism works? Does it require hardware such as timer chip as well?